# Do something when a content is saved

Tags: entities, hooks

I'm a total beginner in module coding and i'm trying to adapt a simple D7 module which is updating a field from a content type from an external API when the content is created or modified.

On an fresh D9 install, i've created a module named : edu_module

Created a folder /custom/edu_module in the module directory

Created a edu_module.info.yml

Activated the module => OK

and at last created an `edu_module.module` file with this code :

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function edu_module_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  \Drupal::logger('edu_module')->alert('page updated by me');
  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Page has been updtaed by me: ' . $entity->title->value);
}
```

And nothing happen. I've tried two different way to obtain information (logger & messenger) but i have no results. I think hook is probably not fired but why not ?
Can anyone help ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: After adding a hook to a module, you need to clear the Drupal cache at least once for the hook to start working.

Comment: Thanks, i feel a bit stupid :) 
I've done multiple try and cache what not cleared on this last one.